# Pandas for-loop with a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open links in my dataframe using selenium webdriver, the dataframe 'df1' looks like this:

|  | user | repo1 | repo2 | repo3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | breed | cs149-f22 | kattis2canvas | grpc-maven-skeleton |
| 1 | GrahamDumpleton | mod_wsgi | wrapt | NaN |

The links I want to open include the content in column 'user' and one of 3 'repo' columns. I encounter a bug when I iterate the 'repo' columns.

Could anyone help me out? Thank you!

Here is my best try:

```
repo_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if 'repo' in col]

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    user = row['user']
    for repo_name in repo_cols:
        try:
            repo = row['repo_name']
            current_url = f'https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/graphs/contributors'
            driver.get(current_url)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except:
            pass
```

Here is the bug I encounter:

```
KeyError: 'repo_name' 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'repo_name'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-eb068230c3fd> in <module>
      4     user = row['user']
      5     for repo_name in repo_cols:
----> 6         repo = row['repo_name']
      7         current_url = f'https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/graphs/contributors'
      8         driver.get(current_url)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'repo_name'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the quotation mark on the:

> repo = row['repo_name']

It should be:

> repo = row[repo_name]

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `KeyError` because there is no column named `repro_name`.
You need to replace `row['repo_name']` with `row[repo_name]`.

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

df1= pd.DataFrame({'user': ['breed', 'GrahamDumpleton'],
 'repo1': ['cs149-f22', 'mod_wsgi'],
 'repo2': ['kattis2canvas', 'wrapt']})

repo_cols = [col for col in df1.columns if 'repo' in col]

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    user = row['user']
    for repo_name in repo_cols:
        try:
            repo = row[repo_name]
            browser=webdriver.Chrome()
            current_url = f'https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/graphs/contributors'
            browser.get(current_url)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I really wish I can accept more than 1 answer.